# Logic app doe snot resume after calling webhook

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that calls API endpoint through APIM. when I call endpoint in the logic app using the webhook connector, webhook keeps running and doe snot resume logic app.

While if I tried the same API endpoint through postman, it respond back within 3-5 seconds.

Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Not sure if i am missing anything.

Comment: Can you please try with the HTTP connector instead of the HTTP webhook https://i.imgur.com/Iy5lkB4.png

Comment: @SwethaKandikonda-MT my request is long-running API so I can not use the HTTP connector

Answer (score 0):

This is outside the intended use of the webhook http task.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-webhook

You'll want to use the regular http post task, but you can extend the timeout in the settings to accommodate your long-running http call.
(click the triple dots in the top-right, then utilize the "Action Timeout" setting).
You could also try disabling asyncronous behavior:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#avoid-http-timeouts-for-long-running-tasks

If the logic app still times out, you will probably need to design a different solution.